# What type to be declared for axios incoming data from backend in my typescript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

This is typescript code, I figured out type for e(function is used for from submittion is it correct type?) and in catch block type "any" is used for an error what should ideal type for that, what type needs to declared for json data coming from the backend.

```js
const ResetPassword = async (e : React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) =>  {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
        if (info.password !== info.confirm_password) {
            toast.error("Password don't match")
        }
        else {
            interface res {
                message : string;
                success : boolean;
            }
            const response = await axios.post('/api/resetpassword',
            {
                token : info.token,
                password : info.password
            })

            const responseData :  res = response.data

            if(responseData.success) {
                toast.success(responseData.message)
                router.push('/login')
            }
            else {
                toast.error(responseData.message)
            }
        }
        } catch (error : any) {
            toast.error("Something went wrong")
        }


    }
```

Is there better any better to write a above code much efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `AxiosResponse` & `AxiosError` provided by the axios library,
as long as you have correctly installed the types package `@types/axios`

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios';

try {
    const response: AxiosResponse<ExpectedType> = await axios.post('/api/resetpassword', {
        token: info.token,
        password: info.password
    });
} catch (error: AxiosError) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: const response = await axios.post. here what type has to be utilized?

Comment: i tried but it right type, is shows red swingly line below 'AxiosError' error has for try catch block.

Comment: check the updated answer, they also have a good documentation about this, it's a good idea to first read the doc thoroughly